# delphi 11 KeyStore file and alias

Tags: android, delphi, deployment, google-play, provisioning

in my project option, on deployment/provisioning page, after create KeyStore file, when creating alias, alias password box is disabled. why? what can i do?

I have created a KeyStore file. I entered a alias name, but the password box is disabled